# Optimize linq query by storing value in select

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have problem with linq query. In Select I am getting the same item twice which makes code execution much longer than I can afford. Is there any way to store `x.OrderByDescending(z => z.Date).FirstOrDefault()` item inside `Select` query?

Execution time: 180 ms

```
var groups = dataContext.History
    .GroupBy(a => new { a.BankName, a.AccountNo })
    .Select(x => new HistoryReportItem
    {
        AccountNo = x.FirstOrDefault().AccountNo,
        BankName = x.FirstOrDefault().BankName,
        IsActive = x.FirstOrDefault().IncludeInCheck,
    })
    .ToList();
```

Execution time: 1200 ms

```
var groups = dataContext.History
    .GroupBy(a => new { a.BankName, a.AccountNo })
    .Select(x => new HistoryReportItem
    {
        AccountNo = x.FirstOrDefault().AccountNo,
        BankName = x.FirstOrDefault().BankName,
        IsActive = x.FirstOrDefault().IncludeInCheck,
        LastDate = x.OrderByDescending(z => z.Date).FirstOrDefault().Date,
    })
    .ToList();
```

Execution time: 2400 ms

```
var groups = dataContext.History
    .GroupBy(a => new { a.BankName, a.AccountNo })
    .Select(x => new HistoryReportItem
    {
        AccountNo = x.FirstOrDefault().AccountNo,
        BankName = x.FirstOrDefault().BankName,
        IsActive = x.FirstOrDefault().IncludeInCheck,
        LastDate = x.OrderByDescending(z => z.Date).FirstOrDefault().Date,
        DataItemsCount = x.OrderByDescending(z => z.Date).FirstOrDefault().CountItemsSend
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This could be a good question for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @dymanoid With more context, possibly. But it's a bit on the shallow side as it currently stands for CR.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing the select in two steps:

```
var groups = dataContext.History
    .GroupBy(a => new { a.BankName, a.AccountNo })
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        first = x.FirstOrDefault();
        lastDate = x.OrderByDescending(z => z.Date).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    .Select(x => new HistoryReportItem
    {
        AccountNo = x.first.AccountNo,
        BankName = x.first.BankName,
        IsActive = x.first.IncludeInCheck,
        LastDate = x.lastDate.Date,
        DataItemsCount = x.lastDate.CountItemsSend
    })
    .ToList();
```

If this fails, it might be because the engine can't convert it completely to SQL, and you can try adding an `AsEnumerable()` between the two `Select`s.